# How to produce output of two values in the form of an equation rather than just the output?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a simple JavaScript program and i want the output in form of an equation e.g 2 x 2 = 4. i want such exact equation as the output. The code is below. any help?

```
<script>
function input() {
  value1 = 1 * prompt("1st number", 0);
  value2 = 1 * prompt("2nd number", 0);
  document.getElementById("v1").innerHTML = (value1)
  document.getElementById("v2").innerHTML = (value2)
}

function output() {
  document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = (value1 * value2);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```js
function input() {
  value1 = 1 * prompt("1st number", 0);
  value2 = 1 * prompt("2nd number", 0);
  document.getElementById("v1").innerHTML = (value1)
  document.getElementById("v2").innerHTML = (value2)
  output()
}

function output() {
  document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = `${value1} * ${value2} = ${value1 * value2}`;
}

input();
```

```html
<div id="v1"></div>
<div id="v2"></div>
<div id="check"></div>
```

Comment: While this code answers the question, please provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question.